# Change the licensed to name in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio-2012

i'm having trouble being able to change the "licensed to" in visual studio 2012. if i publish an app it's coming out as "HP" and it needs to be from me. I found an article online about this but the steps don't seem to be logical.

can anyone help me with this?

here is the article that i found:

http://blog.brouwer.pro/2012/09/how-to-change-licensed-to-name-for-visual-studio-2012/

the problem is for step 2 in the registry i don't have "username" and also for step 4 i don't know what this is (replace the placeholder with your own username)

any help would be amazing!!!

Comment: It's not straight forward, so quite possibly the "steps don't seem to be logical", but without linking the article it's hard to even guess what you found.

Answer (score 2):

If the `UserName` value does not exist in `Registration`, you'll need to create it yourself.

Just create it as a new string value, and set the value to your name.

The "(replace the placeholder with your own username)" just means to replace `{YOUR_USER}` in the given path with your user name.

For example if your user name is 'Superior', navigate to `C:\Users\Superior\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0`

Comment: yeah i mean i changed everything in the registry, deleted the .dat file and it still shows licensed to HP. so frustrating.

Comment: @BSanders HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion (remove the "Wow6432Node" part if not on a 64-bit OS) also has registration info in RegisteredOwner and RegisteredOrganization. I updated that to change the organization and ran `devenv /setup` as admin, and it updated the splash. I have the same name in both though, so I can't be sure which has effect.